# Multiple image arrays with prev and next buttons on one webpage javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, button

I'm an absolute beginner with javascript and stuck on the last thing for the website I'm building. I have four image arrays on one webpage, all four have the same prev and next buttons. When I put the javascript files in the HTML of all the arrays this is what happens.
When you click on the prev and next buttons of arrays 1, 2, or 3, the images of array 4 are moving. If you use the prev or next button of array 4 nothing happens. How would it be working for each array? I hope to find a solution. You will help me a lot!

```
<!--just the html of two arrays-->
<div><img src="images/boek_tantes01.jpg" class="detantesboek-images"></div>
    <div><button class="pijl-links" id="prev_01"><img src="images/pijl_links.svg"></button></div>
    <div><button class="pijl-rechts" id="next_01"><img src="images/pijl_rechts.svg"></button></div>
</div>
<div></div>

<div></div>
<div>
<div><img src="images/boek_se_1.jpg" class="detantesspec-images"></div>
    <div><button class="pijl-links" id="prev_02"><img src="images/pijl_links.svg"></button></div>
    <div><button class="pijl-rechts" id="next_02"><img src="images/pijl_rechts.svg"></button></div>
```

The javascript of two arrays, the other two are the same only with different file names. I have tried different button names. I can solve it to make 4 separate pages but I don't prefer this.

```
var slider_img = document.querySelector('.detantesboek-images');
var images = ['boek_tantes01.jpg', 'boek_tantes02.jpg', 'boek_tantes03.jpg', 'boek_tantes04.jpg', 'boek_tantes05.jpg', 'boek_tantes06.jpg','boek_tantes07.jpg'];
var current_image = 0;

document.getElementById("prev_01").addEventListener("click", prev);
document.getElementById("next_01").addEventListener("click", next);

function prev(){
    if(current_image <= 0) current_image = images.length;   
    current_image--;
    return setImg();             
}

function next(){
    if(current_image >= images.length-1) current_image = -1;
    current_image++;
    return setImg();             
}

function setImg(){
    return slider_img.setAttribute('src', "images/"+images[current_image]);
    
}

var slider_img = document.querySelector('.detantesspec-images');
var images = ['boek_se_1.jpg', 'boek_se_2.jpg', 'boek_se_3.jpg', 'boek_se_4.jpg', 'boek_se_5.jpg'];
var current_image = 0;

document.getElementById("prev_02").addEventListener("click", prev);
document.getElementById("next_02").addEventListener("click", next);

function prev(){
    if(current_image <= 0) current_image = images.length;   
    current_image--;
    return setImg();             
}

function next(){
    if(current_image >= images.length-1) current_image = -1;
    current_image++;
    return setImg();             
}

function setImg(){
    return slider_img.setAttribute('src', "images/"+images[current_image]);
    
}
```

Comment: If anyone has the same problem, this is the solution. [link]https://codepen.io/shade97/pen/GRmdexM [link]https://www.shawndsilva.com/blog/web-development/multiple-image-galleries-in-a-single-page-using-javascript